# How to add additional information to chart.js tooltip?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, ng2-charts, ngx-charts

I want to to add additional information to the below bar chart  tooltip. i.e After `Base: 495888` I want to display `myData: 20%`.  Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Stackblitz Demo [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacked-bar-charts-njmxag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)